# ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined, While Compress Image

Tags: java, android, interface, exif, image-compression

I want to **compress** all images from a folder and I used [this Compressor library](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor).

I got this type of warning while compressing files, I can't understand I got this **warning for image compress or override interface method**.

> ```
> ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 544 
> Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 545 
> Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 546 
> Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 547 
> Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 548 
> Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 549 
> Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 2
> ```

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void setQualityRatio(Integer qualityNum) {
    for (int i=0; i<orgFileList.size(); i++){
        try {
            File file = new Compressor(CompressMultipleActivity.this).setQuality(qualityNum).compressToFile(orgFileList.get(i));
            currFileList.set(i, file);
            
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(CompressMultipleActivity.this, "Failed to compress image, Try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

What is my problem here? Why did I get this warning and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this library is outdated and it uses built-in `ExifInterface` which lacks a lot of tag definitions, instead of [support `ExifInterface`](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html) which gets updated regularly.

Comment: This can he crash or throw exception? or it's just produce warning.

Comment: and have any good library for image compressor that haven't this issue?